# Spring Boot: Override Value Parameter with Empty String

Tags: spring-boot

Say I have a value defined like this in code:

```
@Value ("${com.example.myKey:}")
private String myKey;
```

And an application.yaml with this defined in it:

```
com:
  example:
    myKey: abc123
```

If I want to override this at runtime with an empty string, I would expect to be able to pass an environment variable like this:

```
export COM_EXAMPLE_MYKEY=""
```

It doesn't work, though, and the value defined in application.yml continues to be used. Can anyone tell me whether this is possible / I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: try passing `com.example.myKey` instead of `COM_EXAMPLE_MYKEY`

Answer (score 0):

According to your profile,

```
com:
  example:
    myKey: abc123
```

I think this one should be

```
@Value ("${com.example.myKey}")
```

?

I'm using springboot 2.0.4. Looks work.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed my fake example -- you are correct, though, based on what I originally provided.